# How to determine is message was sended by QuickFix

Tags: connection, quickfix

Actualy my problem touches network connection. Assume my program is sending some message and exactly at this moment network connection is down. As I realized, QuickFix notifies me with Application.onLogout. But I might call Session.sendToTarget before recieving onLogout. This is difficult situation and I need to know exactly was my message sent or wasn't. Is there a way to determine this?

Thanks for your answers

Comment: Why do you need it ? Isn't that the whole point of using a standardised protocol, to worry about the message rather than how you create it.

Comment: Assume, user creates an order and sending it via quickfix. User must be notified that connection is down and order wasn't sent.

Comment: Even then what engine you are using isn't required. If the correct message with the required tags are present everything is fine. Not all financial institutions use the same engine, how do you think they get away with it ? Requiring to know what engine was used would make it futile to use a standardised messaging.

Comment: Totally agree with you. But, evidently, there is misunderstanding. I was asking about just my code. Is it possible to know exact result of send operation. Now I realized. Resend request from counterparty helps me.

Comment: My bad, I only read the title, didn't check out your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pelasse take a look here:
[How to determine if message is sent through QuickFIX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11101819/how-to-determine-if-message-is-sent-through-quickfix)

And put your attention at the heartbeat messages.

Comment: Thanks. I was hoping that there is an easier way like return result.

Comment: @Alexey.Popov: the FIX is a great and solid standard, if you'll start to code you'll see what I'm writing. Trust me.